# Unsigned int fields seem wrongly typed to System.Int32 by System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unsigned-integer

Using `System.Data.SQLite`, I am creating a table with unsigned integer columns:

```
@"CREATE TABLE widgets (" +
    @"id unsigned integer(10) PRIMARY KEY, " +
    @"fkey unsigned integer(10), " + ...
```

and then insert values like

```
INSERT INTO widgets (id, fkey, ...) VALUES (4294967295, 3456, ...
```

However, looping over rows and columns of this table I discover that `row["id"]` has type `System.Int32` (rather than `UInt32`) and, no surprise, 4294967295 is interpreted as -1. Actually, all unsigned int fields in the table (not only the primary key id are incorrectly typed as `System.Int32`)

Meanwhile the SQLite type specification says that integers are stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value. 4294967295 = 0xFFFFFFFF fits in just four bytes. It also seems at odds with the SQLite's so-called "dynamic typing". When I insert bigger than 4294967295 positive values, the type remains `System.Int32`.

Is it a bug or a feature?

PS1:

my table contains 1 row with column id=2^32-1=4294967295 (or bigger), and I print types of all columns with

```
public void PrintDataTypes(DataTable dt) {
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            Console.WriteLine("name={0}, type={1}", 
                               col.ToString(),
                               row[col].GetType().ToString());
        return; // after 1st row is done
    }
}
```

And I invariably get

```
name=id, type=System.Int32
name=fkey, type=System.Int32
...
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html - as far as I know SQLite ignores the "unsigned" keyword and the size specifier. To determine why you are seeing `Int32` you may want to post the code you use to read from the table.

Comment: Thanks! I added PS1 to the original post to explain how I get System.Int32

Comment: Citing the reference you suggested:The INTEGER storage class, for example, includes 6 different integer datatypes of different lengths. This makes a difference on disk. But as soon as INTEGER values are read off of disk and into memory for processing, they are converted to the most general datatype (8-byte signed integer).

Comment: In SQLite, all integer have the same type, signed 64 bits. (Smaller storage is just an optimization). Using `Int32` looks like a bug in the DB driver.

Comment: Still missing is how the SQlite table becomes a DataTable. Could be a  mis-configuration of the Adapater or the Table. Are they strongly typed, what is the SELECT query?

Comment: In many databases, the integer values are always signed. However, in most languages you can safely cast them to unsigned without issue. For example in C#, `uint val = (uint)signedIntegerValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get an unsigned integer column in SqLite, even though you specified unsigned in your SQL. Yes, I personally consider that to be a glaring deficiency - it does not even output a warning upon seeing your "unsigned" specification within your SQL. Thus, your column is 64-bit signed, and your maximum value that you can store is indeed 2 to the 63rd power.